# How can I dynamically add labels and checkboxes from a C# object or method to a fieldset using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, dynamic, razor

I need to populate a fieldset on a page with pairs of labels/checkboxes that will differ from user to user. Currently I've got this hardcoded in HTML like so:

Old HTML:

```
    <fieldset id="checkBoxesFieldset" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="groupedSites">
        <legend class="labelText">Select the Duckbilled Platypi that you want to include in your backyard menagerie</legend>
        <label for="duckbill1">1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="duckbill1" id="duckbill1" />
        <label for="duckbill2">2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="duckbill2" id="duckbill2" />
```

. . .

I reckon the new HTML should be like this:

```
    <fieldset id="checkBoxesFieldset" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="groupedSites">
        <legend class="labelText">Select the Duckbilled Platypi that you want to include in your backyard menagerie</legend>
    </fieldset>
```

...and the C# and jQuery in my page something like this (the jQuery is extreme pseudocode, but hopefully you can get the idea of what I want to accomplish):

```
{//Razor    
    ...
    List<string> Platypi = getPlatypi();
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $.each(string s in @Platypi) {
        $("#checkBoxesFieldset").html.Add.Label(s);
        $("#checkBoxesFieldset").html.Add.Checkbox();
    }
}
```

How exactly should this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you access a string array:

```
   string[] sites = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "7", "42" };
```

...you can do it this way:

```
@foreach(var site in sites) { 
     @Html.Raw("<label for=" + site + ">" + site + " </label>");
     @Html.Raw("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=" + site + " id=" + site + " />");
}
```

If you want to use an object in a Model to populate, though:

```
@foreach(var site in Model.ListSites) { 
       @Html.Raw("<label for=" + @site.ToString() + ">" + @site.ToString() + " </label>"); 
       @Html.Raw("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=" + @site.ToString() + " id=" + @site.ToString() + " />");
}
```